# IBM Watson Node-SDK use pipe input instead of file

Tags: node.js, ibm-watson

I want to use pipe input from console.
How do I use stream input from process.stdin instead of speech.wav

```
var recognizeStream = speechToText.recognizeUsingWebSocket(params);

// pipe in some audio
fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/speech.wav').pipe(recognizeStream);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to treat `process.stdin` as a stream. So in your case.

```
process.stdin.pipe(recognizeStream);
```